# How to edit the default comment title?

Tags: themes, comments

I want a code so when there are (or is) two comments on the post, it automatically changes the title to "Add Your Voice To The Topic!".

What is the code for this?

Comment: When you ask questions, please search SE to see if there are already answers to your questions, if not take the time to try to resolve this problem and then share your code for advice - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/337368/7968

Comment: Thank you. Yes I usually search before asking. I think my question is different. I am not looking to just change the default title. And I don't want to limit it to specific pages. I want to keep the current title, and change it when there two comments or more on the post. so from the third comment, it shows the new title.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try somthing like this - untested...

```php
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'wpse379939_comment_form_modification');
function wpse379939_comment_form_modification($defaults){

    // check if we have 2 or more comments..
    if ( get_comments_number() >= 2) {

        $defaults['title_reply'] = __('Add Your Voice To The Topic!');   

    }

    return $defaults;

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. it shows the number of comments only.